# Multiple array results in a variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

I've some PHP code:

```
$categories = mysql_query("SELECT category_id, category_name AS categories FROM categories");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories)){
        $columnvalues[] = $row['categories'];
}

$catlist = $columnvalues[0];

$catchq = mysql_query("SELECT message AS message FROM box WHERE LOWER(message) LIKE '".$catlist."'");
$catchr = mysql_fetch_array($catchq);
$catchx = $catchr['message'];
echo $catchx."\n";
```

The above code works as intended, but only for the [0] match and if the message contains the name of the category for [0]. What I am trying to accomplish is to have the second query look for any of the four categories found in the first query.

How would I match it against [1], [2], [3] as well? I tried an OR operator, but it doesn't work as I think it would (eg. `$catlist = $columnvalues[0] or $columnvalues[1];`)

Comment: Do not you MySQL function, instead use MySQLi

Comment: Try with regexp: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: @savafa why? i mean, i know why, but just saying that without explaining why doesn't do much good. besides, it doesn't really matter here—he's not putting any user-supplied data into the queries, so there's no risk of injection.

Comment: @sgroves, it's really not all because of injection risk, the MySQL is deprecated and is not supported anymore and will be removed sooner or later.

Comment: should have said that in the first place :P  btw mysqli kind of sucks too; there's no reason not to just use pdo unless the performance difference matters in your application (in which case ... why would you be using php?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just loop over `$columnvalues`:

```
$query = "SELECT message AS message FROM box WHERE LOWER(message)"
foreach ($columnvalues as $key => $value) {
    if ($key) {
        $query .= " OR ";
    }
    $query .= " LIKE '%$value%' ";
}
$catchq = mysql_query($query);
```

---

Your code is vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: @sgroves any query that uses concatenation is vulnerable, so `LIKE '%$value%'` is a vulnerability

Comment: really? how would you, as a malicious user, exploit this "vulnerability"? `'select * from ' . 'potatoes'` is a query that uses concatenation too. is it vulnerable?

Comment: @sgroves I meant concatenation of variables; perhaps I should have said interpolation

Comment: my point still stands. concatenating variables is only a vulnerability if the variables being concatenated might contain user input. that's not the case in the code in question.

Comment: @sgroves how do you know that the contents of the `categories` table does not contain user input?

Comment: how do you know he doesn't sanitize database input? :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29942/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-sgroves)

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills. Your code gave me an indication which way to go with. I got it working exactly the way I want it now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use MySQLi, since MySQL is deprecated.
This can do what you want to do:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuname, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$categories = $mysqli->query("SELECT `category_id`, `category_name` AS `categories` FROM `categories`");

while ($row = $categories->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        $columnvalues[] = $row['categories'];
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `message` FROM `box` WHERE LOWER(`message`) LIKE ?"); 
foreach($columnvalues as $value){
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $value);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($message);
        $stmt->fetch();
        printf("%s: %s<br>", $value, $message);
}
$stmt->close();
```